# Python name space issues with ipython parallel

Tags: python, python-2.7, parallel-processing, ipython

I'm starting to experiment with the IPython parallel tools and have an issue.  I start up my python engines with:

```
ipcluster start -n 3
```

Then the following code runs fine:

```
from IPython.parallel import Client

def dop(x):
    rc = Client()
    dview = rc[:]
    dview.block=True
    dview.execute('a = 5')
    dview['b'] = 10
    ack = dview.apply(lambda x: a+b+x, x)
    return ack

ack = dop(27)
print ack
```

returns [42, 42, 42] as it should.  But if I break the code into different files:
dop.py:

```
from IPython.parallel import Client

def dop(x):
    rc = Client()
    dview = rc[:]
    dview.block=True
    dview.execute('a = 5')
    dview['b'] = 10
    print dview['a']
    ack = dview.apply(lambda x: a+b+x, x)
    return ack
```

and try the following:

```
from dop import dop
ack = dop(27)
print ack
```

I get errors from each engine:

```
[0:apply]: NameError: global name 'a' is not defined
[1:apply]: NameError: global name 'a' is not defined
[2:apply]: NameError: global name 'a' is not defined
```

I don't get it...why can't I put the function in a different file and import it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Quick answer:  decorate your function with `@interactive` from `IPython.parallel.util`[1] if you want it to have access to the engine's global namespace:

```
from IPython.parallel.util import interactive
f = interactive(lambda x: a+b+x)
ack = dview.apply(f, x)
```

The actual explanation:

the IPython user namespace is essentially the module `__main__`.  This is where code is run when you do `execute('a = 5')`.

If you define a function interactively, its module is also `__main__`:

```
lam = lambda x: a+b+x
lam.__module__
'__main__'
```

When the Engine unserializes a function, it does so in the appropriate global namespace for the function's module, so functions defined in `__main__` in your client are also defined in `__main__` on the Engine, and thus have access to `a`.

Once you put it in a file and import it, then the functions are no longer attached to `__main__`, but the module `dop`:

```
from dop import dop
dop.__module__
'dop'
```

All functions conventionally defined in that module (lambdas included) will have this value, so when they are unpacked on the Engine their global namespace will be that of the `dop` module, *not* `__main__`, so your 'a' is not accessible.

For this reason, IPython provides a simple `@interactive` decorator that results in any function being unpacked as if it were defined in `__main__`, regardless of where the function is actually defined.

For an example of the difference, take this `dop.py`:

```
from IPython.parallel import Client
from IPython.parallel.util import interactive

a = 1

def dop(x):
    rc = Client()
    dview = rc[:]
    dview['a'] = 5
    f = lambda x: a+x
    return dview.apply_sync(f, x)

def idop(x):
    rc = Client()
    dview = rc[:]
    dview['a'] = 5
    f = interactive(lambda x: a+x)
    return dview.apply_sync(f, x)
```

Now, `dop` will use 'a' from the dop module, and `idop` will use 'a' from your engine namespaces.  The only difference between the two is that the function passed to apply is wrapped in [`@interactive`](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/parallel/util.py#L227):

```
from dop import dop, idop
print dop(5)  # 6
print idop(5) # 10
```

[1]: In IPython >= 0.13 (upcoming release), `@interactive` is also available as `from IPython.parallel import interactive`, where it always should have been.