# IPython Parallel Computing Namespace Issues

Tags: python, parallel-processing, ipython, nameerror

I've been reading and re-reading the IPython documentation/tutorial, and I can't figure out the issue with this particular piece of code.  It seems to be that the function `dimensionless_run` is not visible to the namespace delivered to each of the engines, but I'm confused because the function is defined in `__main__`, and clearly visible as part of the global namespace.

`wrapper.py:`

```
import math, os

def dimensionless_run(inputs):
    output_file = open(inputs['fn'],'w')
    ...
    return output_stats

def parallel_run(inputs):
    import math, os  ## Removing this line causes a NameError: global name 'math'
                     ## is not defined.
    folder = inputs['folder']
    zfill_amt = int(math.floor(math.log10(inputs['num_iters'])))
    for i in range(inputs['num_iters']):
        run_num_str = str(i).zfill(zfill_amt)
        if not os.path.exists(folder + '/'):
            os.mkdir(folder)
        dimensionless_run(inputs)
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    inputs = [input1,input2,...]
    client = Client()
    lbview = client.load_balanced_view()
    lbview.block = True
    for x in sorted(globals().items()):
        print x
    lbview.map(parallel_run,inputs)
```

Executing this code after `ipcluster start --n=6` yields the sorted global dictionary, including the `math` and `os` modules, and the `parallel_run` and `dimensionless_run` functions.  This is followed by an IPython.parallel.error.CompositeError: one or more exceptions from call to method: parallel_run, which is composed of a large number of `[n:apply]: NameError: global name 'dimensionless_run' is not defined`, where n runs from 0-5.

There are two things I don't understand, and they're clearly linked.

1. Why doesn't the code identify `dimensionless_run` in the global namespace?
2. Why is `import math, os` necessary *inside* the definition of parallel_run?

**Edited:** This turned out not be much of a namespace error at all--I was executing `ipcluster start --n=6` in a directory that didn't contain the code.  To fix it, all I needed to do was execute the start command in my code's directory.  I also fixed it by adding the lines:

```
    inputs = input_pairs
    os.system("ipcluster start -n 6") #NEW
    client = Client()
    ...
    lbview.map(parallel_run,inputs)
    os.system("ipcluster stop")       #NEW
```

which start the required cluster in the right place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is mostly a duplicate of [Python name space issues with IPython.parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857250/python-name-space-issues-with-ipython-parallel/10859394#10859394), which has a more detailed answer, but the gist:

When the Client sends `parallel_run` to the engine, it just sends that function, not the entire namespace in which the function is defined (the `__main__` module).  So when running the remote `parallel_run`, lookups to `math` or `os` or `dimensionless_run` will look first in `locals()` (what has been defined already in the function, i.e. your in-function imports), then in the `globals()`, which is the `__main__` module *on the engine*.

There are various approaches to making sure names available on the engines, but perhaps the simplest is to explicitly define/send them to the engines (the interactive namespace *is* `__main__` on the engines, just like it is locally in IPython):

```
client[:].execute("import os, math")
client[:]['dimensionless_run'] = dimensionless_run
```

prior to making your run, in which case everything should work as you expect.

This is an issue unique to modules defined interactively / in a script - It does not come up if this file is a *module* instead of a script, e.g.

```
from mymod import parallel_run
lbview.map(parallel_run, inputs)
```

In which case the `globals()` is the module globals, which are generally the same everywhere.

Comment: Both of these solutions work partway, in that they add `dimensionless_run` to the namespace.  However, the functions and classes that are called by `dimensionless_run` are now the ones that come up as missing from the namespace.  There has to be an efficient/pythonic way of sending this data to the engines, without writing out a line of code for every function that needs to be passed along.

Comment: I do one of three approaches, all of which result in complete namespaces: 1. define the functions remotely in the first place with the `%%px` magic (I do this when using the IPython notebook). 2. use modules, where this issue never comes up.  3. make all functions defined locally, but intended to be used remotely, never resolve names outside from globals (100% of names are function arguments or imports within the function).  Yet another option, when working from a script like yours, is to simply push `globals()` (excluding the Client object itself, of course).

Comment: Hmm, I moved all the function-definition code into a module, and moved the `if __name__ == "__main__"` `from perceptions_wrapper import parallel_run
import time, sys
from IPython.parallel import Client`

Comment: (Sorry for the double post) Hmm, I moved all the function-definition code into a module, and moved the `if __name__ == "__main__"...` code to its own script that depends only on:
`from wrapper import parallel_run
from IPython.parallel import Client` 
and I still get the same error.  If I remove the `import math, os` line from parallel_run (which it seems like I should be able to do if I'm importing from the module), they become the first objects missing in the namespace.

Comment: That's bizarre, and not been my experience.  If it didn't work, then calling apply with any module function (e.g. `numpy.linalg.norm` or `json.dumps`) wouldn't work either, and they clearly do, so I don't know what is different about what you are doing without seeing it.  Please provide a *complete* example that reproduces your issue, and perhaps bring it over to ipython-dev or GitHub, which are more appropriate venues to discuss such things in detail.

Comment: Oh, quick question: When you make it a module, is it just in the cwd?  And if so, is the cwd the same for the script and your engines?  For module-imports to work, the module has to be importable in both environments.