# Start IPython Parallel from within another Python script

Tags: python, ipython, ipython-parallel

Suppose I have two Python files

**test.py**

```
from ipyparallel import Client

def hi(a):
    return b + (a * 2)

def run():
    b = 3

    client = Client()
    view = client[:]

    view.push({'b':b})
    results = view.map(hi, [0,1,2,3,4])
    for r in results:
        print(r)
```

and **driver.py**

```
from test import run

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

I get the error **[0:apply]: NameError: name 'b' is not defined**.

This code will work if I call run() from within test.py, however, I do not want to do that. I want to call run() from within driver.py. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python name space issues with ipython parallel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857250/python-name-space-issues-with-ipython-parallel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `test.py` file import `interactive`, then, in `map` function use `interactive(hi)` instead of `hi`:

```
from ipyparallel import Client
from ipyparallel.util import interactive

def hi(a):
    global b
    return b + (a * 2)

def run():
    b = 3
    client = Client()
    view = client[:]
    view.push({'b':b})
    results = view.map(interactive(hi), [0,1,2,3,4])
    for r in results:
        print(r)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```